# How can I block the ASUS Touchpad driver from working on Win10?

Tags: drivers, mouse, windows-10, touchpad

I need to turn the touchpad off, since it is gone crazy and keeps jittering CONSTANTLY. As such, I have tried to do it several times, but it doesn't work.

- Going on the Device Manager, and Uninstalling + Deleting the driver doesn't work. It not only keeps moving on its own, but as soon as I reboot the touchpad is back there
- Clicking on the "Turn touchpad off when a mouse is plugged in" in the ASUS control panel doesn't work
- Installing a new driver and doing the same doesn't work

Where can I find the driver folder? What else can I do to try and disable it?

Comment: Simplest solution.  Don't install the driver.

Comment: Well, I can't *uninstall* it, so...

Comment: Check your BIOS setup. You might find something there.

Comment: Instead of uninstalling try disabling the driver.  The option is there on the right click menu.

Comment: @cybernard I had already tried that. Didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Can you find a driver utility for the touchpad and use that to turn off the touchpad ?

Or is that what you are talking about with the ASUS control panel?

Sounds like you might be stuck in an incompatibility loop. If the driver doesn't work and neither does the disable, you might want to try to clear the driver out again.

Take a look at this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546200(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

what is your laptop model??
My Compaq running windows 10 and I installed windows 7 driver on it, it wont turn off the touch pad while I plugged a mouse
I have to turn it off manually

so it is the driver problem, cause the manufacture doesn't make a windows 10 driver

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can't uninstall a driver by just uninstalling a driver because it leaves Windows in the state of not having a driver.  Windows responds by finding the "best" driver and installing it, which gets you back where you started.
Usually if you REPLACE a driver, then Windows considers that to be the driver you consider best, and leaves it.
You may be able to replace the driver with a generic driver and thereby disable the touchpad.  From Device Manager, device, Properties, Driver tab, Update Driver, select Browse, Let me pick, and choose something generic.  Of course this is quite likely to make the device not work, so make sure that is what you want.
It would be good to know if it is simply the touchpad that jitters, or only when you have the driver.  It is quite likely, using the above procedure, you can force only generic mouse operation of the touchpad (choose a generic mouse driver), and it may work better or worse in that mode.  (Or maybe just disable the "device" related to the driver, as below.)
Even simpler is to just select devices in Device Manager and disable them.  You can do that from Device Manager without worrying about drivers.

Answer (score -3):

Go to setting, Devices, connected device, find your ASUS device, click it and click remove devices.
Uninstall ASUS remote link software and stop the connection of ASUS remote link from your ASUS device.
Additionally, if you using bluetooth to connect your ASUS device, try to disconnect your bluetooth from your computer.

Comment: What makes you think the "remote link" software (which I don't find much mention of) is related to the problem?

Comment: Sorry, i have misunderstood with your problem, try to check this link, maybe it can help you, http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-tms/touchpad-on-asus-laptop-does-not-work-properly/1a6e3775-d7ab-4896-991d-2d925769b7cf